# How to calculate bandwidth?

Tags: bandwidth, transmission

If I have the data of Tx_rate (tranmission rate) and the Rx_rate (receiver rate) values, then how can I calculate the bandwidth from these values.
Also please provide the specific formula for the same.
I have searched to many sources and unable to find out.

Thanks and Regards,
Vivek

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A bit of background: Bandwidth is the maximum amount of data that can be transmitted per unit of time. Bandwidth these days is typically expressed in megabits per second. That said, bandwidth connections can be symmetrical meaning that upload and download capacity is the same, or asymmetrical where the download and upload capacity is not the same. For asymmetrical connections (which includes most broadband connections) the upload capacity is smaller than the download capacity, yet it is the faster download capacity that is normally quoted.

Tx and Rx rates are also expressed in bits per second.

As a first approximation I would take the higher of the Tx and Rx rate and call that your bandwidth requirement.

Better would be to say that your bandwidth requirement equals your Rx (receiver) rate for download and Tx (transmission) rate for upload. (Remembering that most broadband connections are asynchronous, and the upload rate is often hidden away in the small print.)

In reality you never want to run at 100% of your bandwidth and there are always other things on the network that use your bandwidth, so give yourself a margin on top.

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply. so in case of asymmetrical rate of data transmission and receiving,which thing we will consider as bandwidth? should we consider only transmission rate as bandwidth?or is there any formula to calculate bandwidth if transmission and receiving rate are different?

Comment: Like I said, first approximation take the higher figure but to be accurate quote both figures - so your bandwidth requirement is Tx upload and Rx download.